# Why there is a black spot in the display of my iMac?

Tags: display, imac, screen

Yesterday I was working on a project in Adobe illustrator, that project had various white spaces it was then when I noticed a black spot/smudge in the lower corner of the display of my iMac. I thought it must be a dust particle on the outer glass screen of the iMac so I used a microfibre cloth to remove it which eventually failed cause it was then when I realised there is huge black smudge in the actual display of the iMac which is inside the outer glass screen

Comment: Quick test. Photograph the screen. Take a screenshot of the screen. Compare. If it's the screen itself, it won't show on a screenshot.

Comment: The spot doesn't appears in a screenshot the spot appears to be on the LCD itself!

Comment: Then we've eliminated a graphics card or software issue - so, it's either the screen itself, the backlight or the connector cable; I'd suspect the backlight, though I know of no way to test for that, short of 'take it to Apple'. Or it could be something that's got between screen & glass. Post a picture so we can maybe have a better guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha! the black spot is actually dead pixels. I had an Apple Engineer to diagnose the display who said this is an obvious thing to happen and it doesn't happens because of daily usage. So I asked him why does this happens, he said that Apple has the tendency to reuse old and thrown out refurbished, recycled displays which is why sometimes these displays fitted into a brand new $1000 iMac shows these black spots/smudges specially in areas where the speakers are located!

Comment: Apple most certainly does not "reuse  old and thrown out refurbished, recycled displays"  That statement is utter rubbish and I would question this "engineers" competency at this point.  LCDs, like any other tech component , is not immune to failure.

Comment: @Allan God knows what's the truth but this what the Engineer said and I have been using my iMac only for three and a half months and with-in that period of time how can a spot/damage happen to the LCD is a matter to be concerned about!

Comment: Yes, a spot on a 3 month old display is to be a concern.  How can it happen? It's called a defect - this is why you have a warranty.  Regardless, what this "engineer" told you, is flat out wrong.

Comment: @Allan I guess he hates Apple!

Answer (score 0):

Could be dead pixels or a driver issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).